# How can I get they keys from an intersect of two arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays as example:

```
$array1 = ['ASD', 'Ep', 'Com'];
$array2 = [1=>'ASD', 2=>'bob', 3=>'Ep', 4=>'Jam', 5=>'Com'];
```

I want to pull out the keys from `$array2` for which I have a value in `$array1`.

So in this case the expected output would be:

```
array(1, 3, 5)
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Have you tried something ? => Show your effort (pseudo code, code, research, ...)

Comment: yes. I have researched here http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_array.asp for a function - was kinda hoping there was one. And in fact I did look at the array_intersection function...

Comment: ^^ Then show this in your question, edit it, and add this. Show your research and what function you have tried out and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/array_intersect) for this.

```
$array1 = ['ASD', 'Ep', 'Com'];
$array2 = [1=>'ASD', 2=>'bob', 3=>'Ep', 4=>'Jam', 5=>'Com'];

$keys = array_keys(array_intersect($array2, $array1));
```

DEMO: http://codepad.org/GyIrdQpE

Answer (score 2):

You can use the PHP built in function `in_array()`:

```
foreach($array2 as $key => $value) { // loop through $array2 values
    if (in_array($value,$array1)) { // check if current value exists in $array1
        $array3[] = $key; // assign key to $array3
    }
}

print_r($array3); // outputs 'Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 [2] => 5 )'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_intersect($array1, $array2)`. [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

> Sample :

```php
$a1=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue","d"=>"yellow");
$a2=array("e"=>"red","f"=>"green","g"=>"blue");

$result=array_intersect($a1,$a2);
print_r($result);
```

The exit will be:

```
Array
(
    [a] => red
    [b] => green
    [c] => blue
)
```

You can use with **array** and an **associative array** or both **associative array**.

Comment: OP wants the `keys` from `$array2`

Comment: @maxelcat Your arrays always have keys, either 0-based or associative.